# Подключение повторяющегося кода разметки XAML

Tags: xaml, разметка, windows-phone-8.1

Я разрабатываю приложение с множеством страниц, у которых в шапке находятся одни и те-же кнопки и менюшки. Как можно вынести повторяющийся код в отдельную область и просто подключить ее на всех страницах, или единственный выход - яростно заниматься копипастом?

Comment: Все зависит от логики и архитектуры вашего приложения. Думаю тут лучший вариант это создать пользовательский компонент (UserControl) и вынести в него эти действия.

Comment: Я просто представлял себе что есть некоторый аналог PHP функции include, который просто вставляет код разметки из другого файла

Comment: _"есть некоторый аналог PHP функции include, который просто вставляет код разметки"_ -- в xaml можно заменить ControlTemplate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше использовать такой контрол как Frame, тогда в шапке будут кнопки, по клику на которую можно делать

```
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherFile));
```

где AnotherFile, это имя файла (без расширения xaml), да и параметр можно также передавать как обычно.

Comment: Можно ли выполнить данную подгрузку страницы без анимации перелистывания?

Comment: @Олег честно не знаю, не пробовал

Comment: В таком случае пожалуй сам отвечу на свой вопрос, вдруг ищет кто. Через C# Frame.ContentTransitions = null; Через XAML нужно копать <Frame.ContentTransition> <TransitionCollection>. Там полно разных аннимаций переходов, в том числе можно и отключить.